# Karate - Is it feasible to abort a scenario outline with dynamic json array configured in example table

Tags: karate

We are using Scenario outline for one of our use case with dynamic json array configured in example table. Is it feasible to abort the execution when some condition is met in any of the iterarion?
We noticed karate.abort only aborts the current execution scenario row from example table.

Please let me know if you need an example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't use dynamic `Examples`. Use a second feature file in a data-driven loop. Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

So here you have full control to use `karate.abort()` in the "called" feature to break the loop.

Comment: I am sorry, I will definitely track the question(s) I asked in stack-overflow in future.