# How to Skip an Iteration Example in Karate Scenario Outline?

Tags: javascript, karate

I am trying skip an iteration in Karate Scenario outline.
Below is my code

**Scenario Outline:** Skip Iteration
Given url
(Here say <Request_Value> == "Value1" skip the iteration and continue with next one)
Then reqJson.<Request_Value>
And request reqJson
When method POST
Then status 400
**Examples:**
| Request_Value |
| "Value1"      |
| "Value2"      |

Answer (score 0):

You can try if `karate.abort()` does what you want.

Else this may be the only option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961411/143475

You can assume that this is not directly supported in Karate.

That said - do note that there is a way to "tag" specific rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479614/143475